# iPhone/iPad App: Multiple attachments using MessgeUI?

Tags: objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, messageui

Is it possible to attach multiple files to an email using the MessageUI (mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure;

```
[myMailComposeViewController addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:myMime fileName:myFileName];
```

will work for multiple attachments AFAIK.